# JSON unmarshal with HTML escaped strings giving "invalid character 'T' after object key:value pair" error

Tags: html, json, go, escaping, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal a JSON in GO that looks like this:

```json
{
    "label": "The quick &quot;brown fox&quot; jumps over the &quot;lazy dog&quot;",
    "value": "dummy value"
}
```

For this, I am using following code gist:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Label    string  `json:"label,omitempty"`
    Value    string  `json:"value,omitempty"`
}

body := `{
    "label": "The quick &quot;brown fox&quot; jumps over the &quot;lazy dog&quot;",
    "value": "dummy value"
}
`

res := new(Response)
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(html.UnescapeString(body)), &res); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%v", res)
}
```

But specific with the `&quot;` html escaped char, it is giving error as `invalid character 'T' after object key:value pair`.

https://play.golang.org/p/wzvFazO1Swx

**One solution that I can apply over here:**

I can add `\` just before all `&quot;`. So once I unescape using `func UnescapeString(s string) string` function it will make my label field as `"The quick \"brown fox\" jumps over the \"lazy dog\""` and after that, I can easily unmarshal it without any error.

```golang
body = strings.ReplaceAll(body, "&quot;", "\\&quot;")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fD6NdJNnMvS

Please let me know if there is any other and better way I can apply over here.

Comment: Why not do the escape after unmarshal? https://play.golang.org/p/knYEvFv963q

Comment: @mkopriva - that is one more way. But in actual code, I have more fields that can have `&quot;`. For those, I don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface with a custom string type that, *after* unmarshaling itself, does the unescaping.

```golang
type UnescapedString string

func (s *UnescapedString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*string)(s)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *s = UnescapedString(html.UnescapeString(string(*s)))
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/u-hFadUT2_S

Comment: what if I cannot change the `Response` struct as I am using protobuf?

Comment: Unescaping before unmarshaling is plain wrong.

Comment: @VinayGupta are you using [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)?

Comment: @Matteo - actually I am using a third-party API to get the response and unmarshalling it into a protobuf object because I need to pass the object to the down Prediction service (which is in python). For that, I am using `gRPC`.

Comment: @Volker - why shouldn't we do that?

Comment: Because it is wrong. Your JSON isn’t HTML escaped, only some string values are.